# NodeJS/JavaScript: TypeError: person.on is not a function

Tags: node.js

```html
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};

util.inherits(person, events.EventEmitter);

var james = new person('james');
var people = ['james'];

people.forEach(function (person) {
    person.on('speak', function (msg) {
        console.log(person.name + 'said:' + msg);
    });
});

james.emit('speak', 'hey hello');
```

I am getting an error

> person.on('speak', function (msg) {
>
> ```
>        ^  TypeError: person.on is not a function
> ```

events & util are built in modules

Comment: replace with `var people = [ james ];`. You don't want to use a string at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
var people = ['james'];
```

to this:

```
var people = [james];
```

When you put a string in the array, that's what you're going to get when you iterate the array for `.forEach()` and a string `'james'` does not have a `.on()` method so you get the error you see.

Instead, put a reference to your actual object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var people = [ james ];
```

Don't use a `String` object.